# Как правильно отправить запрос?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, vkontakte-api

Я использую VK API, и мне необходимо сохранить картинку на их сервере. Чтобы это сделать, я должен отправить запрос [photos.save](https://vk.com/dev/photos.save?params[v]=5.92). Но есть один вопрос. В параметре photos_list передается json(так расписано у них в инструкции), как правильно мне сформировать URL адрес? Я попытался сделать следующим образом(в `json` лежит словарь [String: Any] со всеми нужными ключами):

```
let str = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.save?album_id=\(json["aid"]!)&server=\(json["server"]!)&photos_list=\(json["photos_list"]!)&hash=\(json["hash"]!)&access_token=\(self.token!)&v=5.92"

let site = URL(string: str)
```

Но в `site` я получаю nil. Попытался сформировать URL без json["photos_list"](т.к. в нем лежит JSON), получил нормальную URL ссылку, но мне необходимо передать параметр json["photos_list"]. Подскажите, как правильно создать URL, чтобы она хранила все нужные параметры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Было бы неплохо добавить в вопрос процесс инициализации переменной `json`. Могу лишь предположить, что она выглядит вот так:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
    "aid": 98754321,
    "server": 123456,
    "photos_list": "[{\"photo\":\"e9f2eba71b:y\",\"sizes\":[[\"s\",\"123456852\",\"e65f\",\"Br4ir9YAvO8\",75,41],[\"m\",\"123456852\",\"e660\",\"Lqpe1N8s8zY\",130,71],[\"x\",\"123456852\",\"e661\",\"tRFbnaIP_4c\",604,330],[\"y\",\"123456852\",\"e662\",\"8JhBOy0qR6o\",748,409],\"kid\":\"569c3da3b168b347315aa5adc92a953a\",\"debug\":\"xsymyxyyyoypyqyry\"}]",
    "hash": "22b333dbbef7cd9b1f9829b5f8713f86",
]
```

В таком случае воспользуйтесь `URLComponents`. С помощью данной структуры Вы сможете проще сгенерировать `URL` для запроса.

Для начала разбейте строку `str` на следующие компоненты:

```
let domain = "https://api.vk.com"
let path = "/method/photos.save"
let queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "album_id", value: (json["aid"] as? Int).flatMap { String($0) } ),
    URLQueryItem(name: "server", value: (json["server"] as? Int).flatMap { String($0) } ),
    URLQueryItem(name: "photos_list", value: json["photos_list"] as? String),
    URLQueryItem(name: "hash", value: json["hash"] as? String),
    URLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: self.token),
    URLQueryItem(name: "v", value: "5.92")
]
```

И теперь Вы легко сможете создать необходимый `URLComponents`:

```
var site = URLComponents(string: domain)
site?.path = path
site?.queryItems = queryItems
```

Протестировать результат можете Вот так:

```
print(site?.url?.absoluteURL ?? "") // Выводит https://api.vk.com/method/photos.save?album_id=98754321&server=123456&photos_list=%5B%7B%22photo%22:%22e9f2eba71b:y%22,%22sizes%22:%5B%5B%22s%22,%22123456852%22,%22e65f%22,%22Br4ir9YAvO8%22,75,41%5D,%5B%22m%22,%22123456852%22,%22e660%22,%22Lqpe1N8s8zY%22,130,71%5D,%5B%22x%22,%22123456852%22,%22e661%22,%22tRFbnaIP_4c%22,604,330%5D,%5B%22y%22,%22123456852%22,%22e662%22,%228JhBOy0qR6o%22,748,409%5D,%22kid%22:%22569c3da3b168b347315aa5adc92a953a%22,%22debug%22:%22xsymyxyyyoypyqyry%22%7D%5D&hash=22b333dbbef7cd9b1f9829b5f8713f86&access_token=token&v=5.92
```

Comment: Вы забыли параметр "hash" для queryItems. После его добавления все заработало исправно, я Вам очень благодарен, теперь буду собирать URL по Вашему способу, намного удобнее, чем в ручную собирать ссыль :)

Comment: @LoonyMan В обновлённой версии ответа я включил `json["hash"]` в запрос. Для того, чтобы не забыть добавить все нужные поля `json`, можно хранить все необходимые ключи в массиве, а затем просто пройтись по нему, взять связанные значения, и объединить их с "access_token" и "v". Но это уже выходит за рамки данного вопроса.